# Error conectadose a un web service con java en eclipse

Tags: java, webservice, eclipse

Estaba trabajando haciendo facturación electrónica y todo funcionaba correctamente, pero de un momento a otro el sistema ya no podia conectarse con el servicio web y me sale el siguiente error

> (Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed
>   to access the WSDL at:
>   https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantes?wsdl.
>   It failed with:
>   https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantes?wsdl.
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:250)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
>   at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77) at
>   ec.gob.sri.comprobanteselectronicos.ws.recepcioncomprobantes.desarrollo.RecepcionComprobantesService.(RecepcionComprobantesService.java:47)
>   at commons.prrue.validarComprobante(prrue.java:10) at
>   commons.prrue.main(prrue.java:20) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://celcer.sri.gob.ec/comprobantes-electronicos-ws/RecepcionComprobantes?wsdl
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
>   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:984)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:385)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:216)
>   ... 12 more)

No entiendo porque puede ser ya que el sistema funcionaba correctamente. Estoy trabajando con el jdk8 y con las libre MITY las versiones 1.1.7

Comment: lo primero que yo haría es validar si el puedes revisar el wsdl en un navegador, ya que este error "Failed to access the WSDL", indica que no tienes acceso a ese servicio, si en el navegador no lo vez, difícil java lo pueda hacer. no es la solución pero podrias comenzar por algo saludos.

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException` es autoexplicativo, creo. Valida que esté disponible el web service